# Matching letters with accent

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex, i use it to split letters and numbers when they are joined:

```
(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})

asd123 //Match
وس123  //Match (Right to left)
وَ123   //No match (The accent is not matched)
```

If the letter have an accent (diacritics) then it will not be matched. I tried adding the `\p{M}` which catches diacritics but i can't seem to make it work.

Comment: [Seems OK to me with \p{M}](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQjRyk)

Comment: Yeah, actually it is, but i was doing it wrong.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but you want to remove numbers and retain anything else why not just use \d+?

Comment: Will it match Arabic numbers ? They are the same but i think they have different unicodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a very simple mistake which is not including the "?" after the `\p{M}`. Without the "?" it will become mandatory and not optional which in my case it is.

```
(?<=\p{L}\p{M}?)(?=\p{N}) //For single diacritic mark
(?<=\p{L}\p{M}\p{M}?)(?=\p{N}) //For single double mark (in Arabic)
```